# How to configure react.js and react-dom.js dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I am new to react and I am not able to configure it correctly the command

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom" 

ReactDOM.render(--,--)
```

is not working even after the locations are given correct.

Comment: if you follow the https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html , it should lead you to basic tutorial

Comment: Can you share your code snipped and package.json file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `create-react-app` then don't need to such setup n all.

just create project and start working on that.

**Quick Start**

```
npx create-react-app my-app   
cd my-app
npm start
```

for proper understanding and learning. please go through [reactjs docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)

Sample app

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
function App() {
  return <div>Hello</div>;
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```